# Hooking Django model intstance's save method to celery

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-s3, celery

I am using S3 as a media storage in Django. The thing is, If the video is uploaded it takes too long to return the response in a view. I know there should be a way to make it async.

snippet of **view.py**

```
with transaction.atomic():
    media = Media(
        med_user_id=account,
        med_path=file,
        med_thumbnail=thumbnail,
        med_assoc_data=data,
    )

   save_async.delay(media)
```

variable **file** is a video with this class`<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile'>`

when I am saving this by `media.save()` it takes 12-20 seconds to complete. I thought to create a celery task that could handle it.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def save_async(self, instance):
    instance.save()
```

I know this doesn't make any sense because it throws a serialization error. 
`Object of type Media is not JSON serializable`
so the question is. how should I make `model.save()` function async with celery?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Celery doesn't understand objects like so. Your best solution is to send the object attributes to the save_async. Yes you will loose the generalization of the your delayed save method. So in this case, you will need to save a reference in the database and send the attributes with the data to the delay method. Example on your above is like so,

in views.py

```
with transaction.atomic():
    media = Media(
       med_user_id=account,
       med_path=file,
       med_thumbnail=thumbnail,
       med_assoc_data=None,    # you can remove this or add a reference to ur S3 upload ID
   )

media.save()

save_async.delay(media.id, data)
```

in tasks.py file

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def save_async(instance_id, data):
    media = Media.objects.get(pk=instance_id)
    media.data = data
    media.save()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: variable file is the main figure in there. thats where video is uploaded. and the problem is it cant be passed through the `.delay()` method because it is not ` JSON serializable`

Comment: Its the same concept. You cant pass a django object to the worker with or without a file. Save the object without the large file, then send its id along with the large data to the worker.

Comment: You cant pass object as an argument, doesn't matter if model is saved or not. I still get the same error `Object of type TemporaryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable` @devdob